# The situation when P is a superset of NP

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np

Could it be that three languages $A, B, C$ such that $A \subset B \subset C$, and $B \in P$, but $A$ and $C$ are $NP$-complete?

Answer (score 5):

Let $L$ be any NP-complete language over $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$, and take
\begin{align}
A &= \{ 0x : x \in L \} \\
B &= 0\Sigma^* \\
C &= 0\Sigma^* \cup \{ 1x : x \in L \}
\end{align}

Comment: Should $L$ be unary over $\Sigma = \{0\}$?

Comment: How do you get $A \subset B$?

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: We don't expect there to exist NP-complete sparse languages.

Comment: Yeah, I was heading off in that direction, but then thought of the other problem, and now it all works perfectly. :)

Comment: Can you explain why B is P?

Comment: It's just the language of all strings starting with zero.